# Display Product Sku in Child Products - Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, sku

On our Magento site, we have it so it displays the SKU under the main product title, but if there are child listings, possibly for different configurations of the product' the sku isn't appearing.
I cant seem to find any layout file associated with that child list, can anyone point me in the right direction to add the SKU to this Child Product List,
An example of what I mean can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gp4U.png

Comment: Do you want to add one more column for sku between Product name and sku?

Comment: I want to add a new line, under the product name in the list of child products for the sku, Just above the price.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the below file:

> vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

to your theme location like below:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

And find the below section in your **grouped.phtml**:

```
<td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

and replace with below code:

```
<td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
    <div class="sku"><?= $_item->getSku() ?></div>
    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

Flush the cache and check.

Comment: Now the whole Child-Products aren't appearing: https://maximcomputer.co.uk/ia-ds1100-2101-sh2347-10-30-vdc.html

Comment: That list of products also is not there even with the default file.

Comment: Are you using grouped product?

Comment: Yes we are. We group products when we import

Comment: Can you if your file using different file for grouped section?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? If you mean what I think, how can I check which file is in use.

Comment: I mean to check the theme you are using that if it uses different template file for grouped products. Can you enable template path hints to check the exact file for grouped products?

Comment: Im using the Hiddentechnies Bizkick theme, there wasn't previously a grouped products folder, just Catalog, CatalogSearch, CatalogWidget, Checkout, Newsletter, Theme. Where is path hints.

Comment: You can enable the template path hint by following this linke: https://magecomp.com/blog/enable-template-path-hints-in-magento-2/

Comment: I don't have the 'Developer' option in the stores configuration.

Comment: I think your magento installation is on default or production mode. You need to set it to developer mode then only Developer option will come.